# Spring Security with Spring Boot: getAuthenticationManager() is null

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and I would like to protect my API with Spring Security. But even after two days of reading tutorials I can't get  it working.

If I do a POST to j_spring_security_check I get the following response:

```
{
"timestamp": 1407420906360,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
"message": null,
"path": "/j_spring_security_check"
}
```

caused by the following Java-Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Line 94 in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is the following. The exception is thrown because getAuthenticationManager() returns null.

```
return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
```

I REALLY don't get why this method returns null. 
This is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider authentificationProvider;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authentificationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .addFilter(getSuccessFilter()).anonymous()
                .authorities(UserRightsProvider.getAnonymousAuthorities())
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    protected Filter getSuccessFilter() {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        return authenticationFilter;
    }
}
```

The application is started the following way:

```
@Order(1)
public class WebAppSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({ "my.packet" })
@PropertySource("classpath:myProperties.properties")
@Order(2)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.showBanner(false);
        application.sources(getClass());
        return application;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in getSuccessFilter you need to have

```
filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManagerBean());
```

You aren't using spring autowiring/DI to make that thing so you have to do everything by hand.  Spring Security Filters (generally) need a handle to auth manager